# Does JSF Managed Bean scope impacts visibility & access between EAR, WAR and JAR

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, managed-bean, ibm-jsf

I have EAR with in Which WAR & few JARS. Eventually few more JARS under my WAR too.

I have packaged a set of DATA OBJECTs inside a EAR as JAR, out which one of its Managed Bean is under 'SessionScope' and with its property -> 'eager = true'. Say 'A.Java'

Now, From My WAR I have a ManagedBean, say 'B.java', with 'RequestScope' trying to get an instance of A.java, Which is returned as NULL. From the Logs, When traced got the below exception:

```
The managed-bean with name 'B' must be application scoped to support eager=true.
```

Is there a hierarchy of Managed Bean Scope, that we have to ensure while archiving and deploying as EAR???

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html

Comment: @TheBitman the docs are clear enough. But the problem here is vice versa... The managed bean A needs to be throughout session, eventually session scoped with eager flag as true and available. Whereas the managed bean B is request scope and trying to get an instance of A. The only problem is, if placed the file 'A' in a JAR outside the war but inside an ear has this issue. Whereas if the file 'A' in a jar is placed inside the WAR's web-inf lib resolves as the B constitute in the web project's java source.

Answer (score 0):

**Eager Application-Scoped Beans**

> Managed beans are lazily instantiated. That is, that they are instantiated when a request is made from the application.
>
> To force an application-scoped bean to be instantiated and placed in the application scope as soon as the application is started and before any request is made, the eager attribute of the managed bean should be set to true as shown in the following example:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
```

The `eager` property means that the container creates the instance at application startup and not on demand. It can put this instance just into the application scope. (There are no other scopes at this time). So the eagerly created managed beans must be `ApplicationScoped`.

Comment: Here invoking file is being asked to be APPLICATION SCOPED.

Comment: "The managed-bean with name 'B' must be application scoped to support eager=true." it doesn't say anything about files. it says : the bean, called B should be ApplicationScoped. There is a meaning to bind a managed bean to a scope, but how would you bind a file to a scope? managed = its lifespan determined by a scope.